# Cannot resolve overloaded method

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark, geolocation, 2dsphere

in Query for Locations Near a GeoJSON Point

```
    val refPoint = Point(Position(-73.9667, 40.78))
    collection.find(Filters.near("geo.coordinates", refPoint, 5000.0, 1000.0)).printResults()
```

I have these errors:
-Cannot resolve overloaded method 'find'
-Cannot resolve overloaded method 'near'

any one have an idea to solve this?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide your imports and build file (`build.sbt`, `pom.xml`, other way to specify dependencies).